# Function named "open" loads a new page - trying to change iframe src with inline JS

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I wrote a simple function for change the `src` attribute of an iframe, and this is the code:

```
function open(dat) {
 document.getElementById('frame1').src = dat;
}
```

I call the function in this way:

```
<table id="maintab1" align="center" border="0" style="width:95%">
      <tr>
        <td width="50%" onclick="open('/timetrials/european/mushroom.php');"> text </td>
        <td width="50%" onclick="open('/timetrials/european/flower.php');" > text </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Of course the iframe has the id 'frame1' as you can see: `<iframe id="frame1" src="/timetrials/european/mushroom.php" >You browser does not support iframes.</iframe>`. The page is correctly loaded on the iframe at first.

When I click on a `<td>`, instead of changing the src of my iframe, I see a new blank page loading forever without getting a result.

Do you know why?

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the `open` function that you've declared, and not `window.open`? Put an alert, or a console.log statement in your function just to be sure.

Comment: Why not create a hyperlink targeting the iframe and leave out JavaScript altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once again, the evils of inline js are clear! This is because there's a property of `window` called `open` and when you use `onlick="open()"` you're calling the wrong `open()`! Don't use inline js!

Read some of these results: **[Why is inline JS bad?](https://www.google.com/search?q=Why%20is%20inline%20js%20bad?)**

**A simple solution to your whole problem** is just to use links targeting the iframe like this:

```
<a href="new/iframe/path" target="myiframe">Change iframe path!</a>
<iframe name="myiframe"></iframe>
```

### Improving your current code:

**[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/iFoWoNa/1/edit)**

**Markup:**

```
<table id="maintab1" >
  <tr>
    <td width="50%" data-open="/timetrials/european/mushroom.php');">Mushroom</td>
    <td width="50%" data-open="/timetrials/european/flower.php');" >Flower</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
//get element references
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('#maintab1 td');

//loop each element
for (var i=0; i<tds.length; ++i) {
  //register click function
  tds[i].addEventListener('click', myClickFunc); 
}

function myClickFunc(event) {
  var link = this.getAttribute('data-open');
  openIframe(link);
}

//also note that camelCase naming is standard
function openIframe(link) {
  console.log(link);
}
```

There are a lot of ways that this could be done, but the key is just getting your element references with javascript and attaching the click function there. Select them however you want to - id, class, selector, or you could even create the element itself with javascript! Rather than storing the data on the element as in my example, you could store them in an array in javascript and then pull them out for each element in the loop (first element will get first link from the array, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my question by changing the name of my function. The name `function open(dat)` causes a conflict with the `window.open`

```
function open_iframe(dat) {
 document.getElementById('frame1').src = dat;
}
```

This is the new code I wrote and it is fine now.

Comment: Please wait and read my answer in a moment when I'm done updating. I really hope you'll not use inline js at all - read here: https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+is+inline+js+bad%3F